# Как получить данные о заголовках ответа и статусе кода запроса при SSLError

Tags: python-3.x, requests

Всем привет, использую библиотеку requests, делаю post запрос на  определенный url, получаю ошибку SSL, в коде библиотеки  место  падения  - модуль adapters.py, функция send:

```py
            if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
                # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
                raise SSLError(e, request=request)
```

Ошибка такого вида:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=url, port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /auth/service/?srv=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))
```

Проблема в  том, что мне нужно  получить код  статуса  в  ответе, так  же заголовки ответа, допустим повторив запрос через фиддлер - я все это получаю,  а вызовом `self.session.request`  я получаю только  ошибку SSL, при этом  конечно заголовки ответа и код статуса из  неё не вытащить, а  этого сильно  хотелось бы, заранее признателен за любую помощь

Comment: `requests.get(url, verify=False)`.

Comment: ну во первых мне  надо сделать  post запрос, однако это  не суть  - внутри requests.post(url, json=json) содержит ровно такой  же вызов через  sessions:
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs), так  что  мы попадаем  ровно в  то же место и никаких заголовков мы  получить не можем

Comment: хотя вроде помогло, спасибо)